# Date convert and add day interval on db2

Tags: sql, db2

I have a line that I'm running in mysql:

```
date_add(convert(:SHIPDATE,date), interval 7 day) as start_date,
```

Which is simply taking a string data type for a date in :SHIPDATE and converting it to a date format as well as making it 7 days in the future.

So if :SHIPDATE is 20181111 then it would make it 2018-11-18

Simple enough and it works but the problem is now I'm moving this script to db2 and this doesn't work. I can't seem to find the function that does this same thing on a non-date data type.

How can I replicate this on db2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the equivalent is:

```
(to_date(:SHIPDATE, 'YYYYMMDD') + 7 DAYS) as start_date
```

Comment: Yes, this worked perfectly! Thank you, I'll accept as soon as it lets me ( 6 minutes)

Answer (score 0):

try `cast('2018-10-01' as date) + 7 days`

You can test this on a Db2 command line via

```
db2 values cast('2018-10-01' as date) + 7 days
```